# Kind of urgent: I need to find the grammatically incorrect sentence, but can't

Tags: grammar, test

folks! So, I was training for a test, but I just can't figure out two questions. In them, I have to identify one excerpt with a grammar mistake. I have the test final results, so I know which sentences are wrong, but I don't know why. Could you please help me? I'm taking this test on June 8 :/

1 - Where is the mistake in the sentence

> Yet in the years since the late 1980s, gyrating oil prices – with the
>   exception of a brief spike during the Gulf War – have become a thing
>   of the past.

2 – What about this one?

> The tower, built in Tokyo's eastern ward of Sumida, will replace the
>   existing Tokyo Tower in 2012.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: These are both complicated sentences, and there are plenty of problems with them, but not any grammatical ones. So we'd need to know what kind of beliefs your teacher has been filling you with, about what's grammatically correct and incorrect in English, and why. There is a lot of nonsense out there.

Comment: Well, for (2), you can't use *will replace* for something that happened seven years ago. But maybe it's an old exercise.

Comment: (1') 'Yet in the years since the late 1980s, gyrating oil prices have – with the exception of a brief spike during the Gulf War – become a thing of the past.' makes the parenthetical adhere more closely to the verb, adjusting more closely  to the adverbial intended, but 'rules' surrounding parentheticals – what their internal grammar has to be and where they should be placed – are hard to find and contentious. Some might prefer (1'') 'Yet in the years since the late 1980s, gyrating oil prices have – the exception here being a brief spike during the Gulf War – become a thing of the past.'

Comment: Sorry, but we can't: [We don't do proofreading unless a source of concern is identified in the text](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so we can specifically address the principles regarding that.

Comment: (2) (We'll ignore the anachronism.) Almost certainly, there is a belief that 'built' here must stand for 'which was  built'. This is a mistake; 'which will be built' is an equally legitimate sense. Stylewise, I'd probably rephrase, but the sentence is grammatical as it stands. // Please read the information at the Help Center, Raphaela, where you will see that 'please point out the mistake's in' questions (proofreading) are off-topic on ELU. // One further point – I prefer 'yo-yoing' to 'gyrating' in (1).

Comment: @Tonepoet but the OP doesn't know where the error is. They only know that the sentences are supposedly wrong. It is not asking whether the examples are grammatically correct or if we can correct it for them. The question is asking "where?".

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A There _is_ no ungrammaticality in the second example. This is proofreading. _And_ the equivalent of homework. Which is why I've answered in a 'comment'. And close-voted.

Comment: @HotLicks do you know where the error might lie? I haven't got a clue.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The fact that the questioner can't identify any specific problem for a proofreading question simply means it can't be brought back into scope. You make an interesting point that this might not be proofreading per the strictest definition of the word, but it is a borderline case. The most likely way to answer this question seems like it would almost have to involve a correction, as the answers made since I commented and voted to close demonstrate, and even if the sentences are assuredly incorrect, identifying the error for the questioner is very similar to proofreading in principal.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OP says that these sentences are excerpts, which means they likely come from a short test essay. Frequently, what is being tested is the correctness of the sentence in the context of the essay. The second sentence may have been extracted from an essay in which the tower has been established as a future project, so for the sentence to be grammatically correct (given the preceding information) it should read, "The tower, to be built in Tokyo's eastern ward of Sumida. . ." This kind of question is common in standardized tests: grammar in context.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yet, in the years since the late 1980s – with the exception of a brief spike during the Gulf War – gyrating oil prices have become a thing of the past.

The parenthetical is there to add extra information about the time and not about the prices and so it should be moved closer to what it describes.

2. The tower – built in Tokyo's eastern ward of Sumida – will replace the existing Tokyo Tower in 2012.

Apart from the illogicality of something that has already come into existence replacing something else only in the future, I would say that since the location of the tower is not the most important point of the sentence, em dashes are the stronger parenthetical mark and will serve to set this extraneous piece of information apart better.

Comment: Much better +1...

Comment: Something can be already built and scheduled to replace another thing in the future. For example the tower may be built, but will only take over roles currently performed by the Tokyo Tower at a later date. In any case that's a semantic not a grammatical error.

Answer (score 0):

Both the sentences have the same grammar mistakes: the actions denoted by the verbs have been completed at a certain point of time in the past. So, the verbs should be in the simple past tense form. The sentences can be corrected as:

> 1. Yet **in the years since the late 1980s**, gyrating oil prices – with the exception of a brief spike during the Gulf War – **became** a
>      thing of the past.
> 2. The tower, built in Tokyo's eastern ward of Sumida,  **replaced** the existing Tokyo Tower **in 2012**.

Comment: "…have become a thing of the past" refers to the (past) 1980s up until the present day, it is ongoing. The Present Perfect is acceptable in this instance. But you may well be right where #2 is concerned.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then, the OP's first sentence is without any error in it, isn't it? Or, perhaps is the error in the subject NP? ***the gyrating/gyration of oil prices has become***?

Comment: But "oil prices" is plural, the auxiliary verb "have" is appropriate and correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA if the subject is "**gyrating or gyration** of oil prices", the head noun is singular (gyrating/gyration).

Comment: What pronoun would you use to replace "***gyrating oil prices***" (please keep to the original wording) **it** or **they**?